# dynamically display data with android

Tags: android, android-layout, dynamic, textview

I have written a layout file to display the data in which i obtained from querying the database. How would you go about this playing the data in a text view though? The purpose of this is to display dynamic content rather than static contect predefined in the resource file.

I don't really want to write

```
 TextView x = new TextView();
 x.setText("...");
 x.setGravity("");
 x...
```

since this is really repetitive and i have to redo for all data that i want to display and also i have everything formatted in an xml file already.

my database function call returns a Cursor object, and i thought I could use the

```
SimpleCursorAdapter();
```

but I cant seem to find the documentation on sending this to the textview.

Does any one have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Say, you have a TextView defined in XML with id **tv**

`TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);`

and want to set text to it after querying from database.

Assume, you have a table with two columns A and B and using a query like:

```
  String q = "SELECT * FROM table_name where(your_condition)";
  Cursor c = db.rawQuery(q, null);
```

Say you want to use the value of column **A** which can be found using  `c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("A"));`

Use the cursor c as below:

```
  if(c.getCount() == 0)
                  {

            //no data found
                  }
                  else  {
                      String j="";
                      c.moveToFirst();
                      do {
                          String cm = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("A"));
                                             j = j+cm;   
                          } while (c.moveToNext());
                      c.close();
```

Now set this text to your TextBox(Dynamic :D ):

```
t.setText(j);
```

---

This is a complete sample : [Database Project](http://www.mediafire.com/?569on9rvb4qoa7w) by me (using a simple approach) which you may try.